# Ionic 4: File: "network_security_config.xml" is not generated

Tags: cordova, ionic4, cordova-android

When running "ionic cordova prepare" the network_security_config.xml does not get created and this causes errors later in the build process.

I have tried changing the resource-file path in the config.xml and remove and readding cordova android as suggested in https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/issues/758 but they did not solve my problem.

Should the network_security.xml file be generated by cordova or do I need to create it manually?

I am using cordova-android 8.1.0.

Answer (score 6):

Deleting the /resources folder and the config.xml file and running: `ionic integrations enable cordova --add` solved this problem.